# Using ssh+socat for remote port forwarding without ssh -R tunnel

Tags: ssh-tunneling

I know that I can use ssh's remote port tunneling to create a connection between remote and localhost like such,

`ssh -fN user@remote -R remote_port:localhost:local_port`

I would like to do the above without the explicit -R. For example...

`ssh -f user@remote "script.sh ${local_port}"`

In which script.sh would call socat to port forward like,

`socat TCP-LISTEN:<some_port_determined_in_script>,fork,reuseaddr TCP:ssh_client:ssh_client_port`

But this is not working. Am I missing something?

Essentially, I would like the client to determine just the client port, and let the remote determine which of its ports to use.

Comment: You can not run the SSH protocol and your own stuff on the same connection. You need two connections: one for SSH and one for your stuff.

Answer (score 1):

When you do not use the -R option, all data will go through the plain ssh channel regardless of different connections (Socat forks). So it might be best to use the -R option like your first example and have Socat forward ports only on the remote localhost, something like:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:<some_port_determined_in_script>,fork,reuseaddr TCP:localhost:remote_port
```